# What is the ideal learning path to building Android apps with Scala, without prior Java experience

Tags: java, android, scala

Unfortunately, there are not currently any books on the subject of 'Learn Android Development with Scala', which would be the ideal solution. I'm guessing that I'll need to pick up at least 3 books here, one for each topic. However, I have no idea what order to read them in, whether to read them simultaneously, what parts of the Java book I can safely skip, etc.

What is the best path for me to get started building Android apps using Scala?

Comment: I think a book on Android and a book on Scala would be sufficient. This post on Stack Overflow covers common issues and so on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476111/scala-programming-for-android

Answer (score 2):

1. The most detailed resource I know for android developers is: http://developer.android.com/index.html
2. developing android apps with scala has not developed to a satisfying standard just yet. you can read about it more here: http://www.slideshare.net/janberkel/android-development-with-scala

Answer (score 2):

You have not stated the reason why you prefer Scala over Java to program android apps.

You need to have a solid foundation in OOP. Also have you looked on Google Code for programming on Scala in Android: http://code.google.com/p/scala-android/ . Also look into this as well: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android

Comment: Cool, thanks for the resources. As for the reason for the Scala over Java preference, I was hoping to keep the discussion related to the actual question. If we turn the discussion into one involving my personal requirements and/or preferences regarding Java vs Scala, it's likely that the answers and resulting discussion would be less generally applicable, and likely of lesser value to others in the future who have the same question but different personal requirements and/or preferences.

Comment: @fourk not necessarily true, the reason Maxood was asking is not to start a "program-language war" of Scala vs. Java which will indeed divert the discussion (like you suggest) but because you might not be aware of Language features, for example, that enable you to achieve the same results in java without taking the path that is "less walked" (Scala for Android). And there are good reasons for that: larger community support, more available online and offline resources etc.